# Cross tab between two Different tables

Tags: sql-server, crosstab

I am stuck in a problem that is to create cross tab between two tables which have no direct relation ..Here are my tables

Employee -- contains employee data

Attendance -- contains Day,Night, Mid-Night, EmpID, From-Date

EmpWages -- contains Wages, FromDate

Cross tab should between Attendance & EmpWages Table

From-Date 1          ............From-Date N            (EmpWages)
Day, Night, Mid-Night...........Day, Night, Mid-Night (Attendance)

Please help me

Comment: Your question is unclear. I also suspect it may turn out too broad. Please specify what you have already tried, what particular difficulties you've got. Also please add some examples to your question: sample data and the expected output based on those data.

Comment: Why don't you create a view and use it for PIVOT?

Comment: Thnx alot Andriy M & BartekR and +1000 for => BartekR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did.

```
USE [FPR]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GAD]    Script Date: 01/26/2012 18:38:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GAD]
As

DECLARE @ReportColumnNames NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @SQLtext NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT  @ReportColumnNames = Stuff( (

SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(YYYY) AS [text()]

FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT YYYY=CAST(FromDate As Date) 

FROM dbo.EmpWages ) x

ORDER BY YYYY

FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @SQLtext = N'SELECT SNo=IDENTITY(int,1,1), * INTO #temp_t FROM (SELECT 
(FromDate) AS OYe, Days = (
CASE A.Day WHEN 1 THEN CAST((E.Wages) AS VARCHAR)
ELSE ''N'' END + SPACE(3) +
CASE A.Night WHEN 1 THEN CAST((E.Wages/2) AS VARCHAR) 
ELSE ''N'' END + SPACE(3) +
CASE A.FullNight WHEN 1 THEN CAST((E.Wages/2) AS VARCHAR) ELSE ''N'' END 
),

E.Name As Employee, D.Name As Department,

SUM(
W.Wages
) OVER(PARTITION BY E.Name) As [Total for Month]

FROM dbo.EmpWages W 

INNER JOIN dbo.Employee E ON
W.EmpID = E.ID

INNER JOIN dbo.Department D ON
E.DeptID = D.ID

JOIN dbo.Attendance A
ON W.EmpID = A.EmpID AND
W.FromDate = A.Date AND W.ToDate IS NULL
GROUP BY E.Name, D.Name, A.Day, A.Night, A.FullNight, A.Advance, FromDate, E.Wages, W.Wages, A.Advance

) as Header
PIVOT (Max(Days) FOR OYe IN(' + @ReportColumnNames + N')) As P1
ORDER BY 1
SELECT * FROM #temp_t 
DROP TABLE #temp_t'

execute (@SQLtext);
```